# How can i bind data from firestore collection to a dropdownfromfield in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection on the Firestore ("fields") and i want to use his collection as an item source to a dropdownform field in flutter application. I am able to create a dropdownfield using static data source but dont know how to bind data from firestore.

here is the code for dropdownform field with static data source.

```
                        DropDownFormField(
                        titleText: "Healthcare Field",
                        hintText: "Please choose one",
                        value: field,
                        dataSource: [
                          {
                            "display": "Running",
                            "value": "Running",
                          },
                          {
                            "display": "Climbing",
                            "value": "Climbing",
                          },
                          {
                            "display": "Walking",
                            "value": "Walking",
                          },
                          {
                            "display": "Swimming",
                            "value": "Swimming",
                          },
                          {
                            "display": "Soccer Practice",
                            "value": "Soccer Practice",
                          },
                          {
                            "display": "Baseball Practice",
                            "value": "Baseball Practice",
                          },
                          {
                            "display": "Football Practice",
                            "value": "Football Practice",
                          },
                        ],
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            field = value;
                          });
                        },
                        textField: 'display',
                        valueField: 'value',
                      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to fill your drop-down list with the names  of the documents you have in a collection you have.

What you need to do is actually retrieve all the documents and save the `document.id` in a list that you will later pass to your drop-down.

An example of getting the document IDs of a collection is the following

```
void getData() {
  databaseReference
      .collection("[COLLECTION]")
      .getDocuments()
      .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    snapshot.documents.forEach((f) => print('${f.id}}'));
  });
}
```

So for your case instead of printing the document ID every time, you need to pass it to your drop-down one ID at a time.